# Parsing specific XML data from webURL - Android

Tags: android, xml, parsing

I would like to parse only one specific River data.
From this website: http://www.arso.gov.si/xml/vode/hidro_podatki_zadnji.xml

My code below extract all Rivers:

ParseApplication.java;

```
public class ParseApplication {

    private String xmlData; // XML file we are processing
    private ArrayList<Application> applications;

    public ParseApplication(String xmlData) {
        this.xmlData = xmlData;
        this.applications = new ArrayList<Application>();
    }

    public ArrayList<Application> getApplications() {
        return applications;
    }

    public boolean process()
    {
        boolean status = true;
        Application currentRecord = null;
        boolean inEntry = false;
        String textValue = "";

        try {
            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            XmlPullParser parser = factory.newPullParser();
            parser.setInput(new StringReader(this.xmlData));
            int eventType = parser.getEventType();

            while(eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                String tagName = parser.getName();
                switch (eventType) {
                    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                        Log.d("ParseApplications", "Starting tag for " + tagName);
                        if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("postaja")) {
                            Log.d("ParseApplication", "Create application item");
                            inEntry = true;
                            currentRecord = new Application();
                        }
                        break;

                    case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                        textValue = parser.getText(); // data itself, used in End_Tag
                        break;

                    case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                        Log.d("ParseApplication", "Ending tag for " + tagName);

                        if (inEntry) {
                            if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("postaja")) {
                                // Save the record and set entry to false
                                Log.d("ParseApplication", "Store Application With Name " + currentRecord.getReka());
                                this.applications.add(currentRecord);
                                inEntry = false;
                            } else if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("reka")) {
                                currentRecord.setReka(textValue); // TextValue already updated
                            } else if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("pretok")) {
                                currentRecord.setPretok(textValue);
                            } else  if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("datum")) {
                                currentRecord.setDatum(textValue);
                            }
                        }

                        break;

                    default:

                        break;
                }

                eventType = parser.next();
            }

        } catch(Exception e) {
            status = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return status;
    }
}
```

and

application.java

```
public class Application {

    private String reka;
    private String pretok;
    private String datum;

    public String getReka() {
        return reka;
    }

    public void setReka(String reka) {
        this.reka = reka;
    }

    public String getPretok() {
        return pretok;
    }

    public void setPretok(String pretok) {
        this.pretok = pretok;
    }

    public String getDatum() {
        return datum;
    }

    public void setDatum(String datum) {
        this.datum = datum;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Reka: " + this.getReka() + "\n" +
                "Pretok: " + this.getPretok() + " m3\n" +
                "Datum: " + this.getDatum();
    }
}
```

How do I parse one specific XML River data only?

Comment: Break the while loop after the first one found. For the rest it is unclear to me what you really want.

Comment: I would like to extract just one RIVER from webURL

Comment: Didnt i already told you how to do that? Yes. So why you ask again?

Comment: I dont know how exactly to do it, can you please tell me how you can do this?

Comment: Google for break statement. And why did you not give better info? I suggested that the first one would do. But maybe you want no 20. Or yet a special one. Why not elaborating?

Comment: Yes I would like to have specific one. Which info would you like to have too?

Comment: Which specific river? How would you know which rivers are in it? Or wouldnt that matter? How do you define a specific river? By the color of the water? Please come to the point.

Comment: But specific, or first one or last one or number 23, to break the while loop can be done always on the same way.

Comment: Each river have specific id and also name...  ID= <postaja sifra="1060" 
NAME= <reka>Mura</reka>  Lets say I would like to have for river Mura and  ID 1060.

Comment: So Mura is the text of tag reke. Ok. Now please define 1060. What is it? It is not the text of tag postaja.  How would you describe it?

Comment: Mura is the first river in the xml file so not a good example if one would try to search the river. Better try to search Ledava. Please adapt your code in such a way that you search for Ledava and then want to break the loop once Ledava is found and you encounter the closing postaja tag.

Comment: `this.applications.add(currentRecord);` Only do that for river Ledaka.

Comment: Maybe:   if(tagAttributePostaja.equals("1060")) {   ?

Comment: Not an answer to the question but ala. Well did you try? I expect you did. Then please report.

Comment: Oh, I tried but I dont know how to do it. I think I need more help:(